# Can't load installed package

Tags: r, package

I wanted to remove a package and then reinstall it because there were new functions I wanted, but now I seem to have a compatibility issue I cannot get rid of.

I did:

```
remove.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

But I get:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.7 is required
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.3

How can I update this `rlang` package and successfully load `dplyr`?

Comment: Install `rlang` first and make sure your R version is up-to-date.

Comment: I get: > install.packages("rlang")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Pol/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rlang’ is in use and will not be installed

Comment: Restart your R session and try to install `rlang` first. Download and install Rtools also from the website provided.

Comment: Ok, restarting and then installing was enough. Thank you.

Comment: Glad the problem is solved but you only need Rtools if on Windows *and* installing from source. CRAN has binaries for Windows, `install.packages("rlang")` would have worked without Rtools installed.

Comment: Just one clarification of what @RuiBarradas wrote:  CRAN only has Windows binaries for recent releases on Windows.  If your R version is too old, you will need Rtools to install packages (but it's probably easier to update R).